# Problem in reading data form mdb file in vb6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

I am using vb6 and trying to read an mdb file into a

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open SqlStr, mvarDB
```

this my criteria string "id = 'SA / -AS 0N' And mp <>'N'", there is a record in the table which id is the above mentioned and its mp column is not N. but when the

```
   rs.MoveFirst
```

in watch window i can see the values of first column. but when below runs , the header says

```
   rs.Filter = sCriteria
```

" : Value Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.> :"
  Appreciate ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the problem was 2 fold onedaywhen comment was helpful but the problem was,

1- the mdb file had worng datatype which was NUMBER so every null in the row caused the record to reach EOF. So i set datatype to TEXT.

2-TO FIND THE NULL IN THE RECORD SET I AM DOING A

```
dataSet.Find sCriteria, adSearchForward 'sCriteria = id = 'NW'
```

Then i check this column if that is not null,

```
If IsNull(dataSet!col1) Then
```

If found the null i use the 'sCriteria = id = 'NW' else  i use id = 'NW' And mp <>'N'.

is working great. The Null was causing the problem as pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree,  Check to make sure you have records first.  You should not need the rs.MoveFirst right off the bat.

```
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

 rs.Filter = strCriteria

End If
```

Also verify that the column you are filtering on actually exists in the Recordset.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If Not rs.EOF Or Not rs.BOF Then is giving -1,  but if it is coming -1 but then howcome i can see the values like rs!id in the watch window which are coming correctly

Comment: how can i see the record set?

Comment: Try setting the CursorLocation property to adUseClient on the recordset before you Open the recordset.

Answer (score 1):

If the `mp` column value is `NULL` then using the Filter criterion `mp <> 'N'` will cause the row to be removed from the filtered resultset.

SQL employs the same [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic). The idea is that `mp <> NULL` evaluated to `UNKNOWN` and results is the row being removed in SQL DML (but retained in SQL DDL...)

If you were using SQL then you could used the predicate `(mp <>'N' OR mp = NULL)`. Sadly, [ADO has a known problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187871) which prevents the use of `NULL` in Filter property criteria.

3VL craziness and ADO bugs should lead you to the conclusion that the `NULL` value should be avoided. Ideally, you should remove `NULL`able columns in the database. In the short term you could ensure your views and procs don't expose the `NULL` value. You could use another 'magic' literal value but perhaps better is to return a suitable default domain value. For example, it could be the case that any value for `mp` that is not `N` must be `Y`:

```
SELECT id, IIF(mp = 'N', 'N', 'Y')
  FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Guard `MoveFirst` with a sanity check like this:

```
If Not rs.EOF Or Not rs.BOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
```

Comment: this is not making any difference. and it is entering the if condition, but the recordcount is 0

Comment: my criteria string is:  "id = 'SA / -AS 0N' And mp <>'N'" and for some columns in mdb there is nothing written for this field i guess it would be null.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to do this

```
rs.MoveFirst
```

the record is automatically position on the first record if anything is found

Next do this

```
If rs.EOF=false Or rs.BOF=false Then
' manipulate recordset here
End If
```